# Disable Internet Explorer 8 Developer Tools

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

Is there a way to either disable Internet Explorer 8 Developer Tools, or at least change the shortcut key mapping?

I'm working on an ASP.NET AJAX app that has used the F12 key for a function for years (it's actually a hold over from the original DOS app).  Customers have used this key for the sam function for nearly 15 years and we'd really like to avoid having to move that function.

Cheers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a DWORD value with the name "**`Disabled`**" to

> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IEDevTools

and give it the value "**`1`**"

Comment: You can also remove it by configuring User or Machine group policy at Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Toolbars\Turn off Developer Tools. This just sets the HKLM or HKCU registry value mentioned by @fretje but is probably easier to configure in an enterprise environment.

Comment: But from experience it's _really_ annoying when firms remove that option, so finding a replacement shortcut would be a much better solution.