# Why isn't my IE8 Developer Tools working?

Tags: ie-developer-tools

It used to work and now when I press F12 nothing happens...the window does NOT appear. I've uninstalled any other toolbars I've installed and tried resetting by security settings in IE...nothing.

I'm using Windows 7 beta

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Maybe someone disabled them?
[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944323/disable-internet-explorer-8-developer-tools) how you do that.

Basically: Check the following registry key:

> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IEDevTools

In the worst case you can remove the whole key. This wil revert the settings back to default.

Comment: thank you very much.  That actually wasn't the problem, but close.  I looked in the register and found these keys:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IEDevTools]
"WindowPos"=hex:00,83,ff,ff,00,83,ff,ff,a0,83,ff,ff,26,83,ff,ff
"Pinned"=dword:00000000
"UseDevToolsDebugger"=dword:00000001

erasing these keys brought the toolbar back.

Comment: You're a star! I did have the problem that the window would appear on my Windows toolbar, but that I couldn't maximize it in any way, so it was always hidden. After deleting the reg values it started working again.

Comment: Superstar. I don't know how this happened to me, but it's bloody irritating.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, the developer tools were disabled by Group Policy.

1. Open the Local Group Policy Editor. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run window, and type `gpedit.msc` in the search line and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. In the left pane click on to expand *Computer Configuration*, *Administrative Templates*, *Windows Components*, *Internet Explorer*, and select *Toolbars*

   1. If you can't find the appropriate policy, you might need to add it. Right click on *Administrative Templates*.
   2. Select *Add/Remove Templates...*
   3. Select *Add...*
   4. I went for broke and selected a whole bunch of templates to be sure I got the one I needed.
3. In the right pane double-click *Turn off Developer Tools*
4. Select *Disabled* to disable the disablement.
5. Close the Group Policy editor.
6. You might have to close IE or restart your computer to apply the setting.

Answer (score 11):

The problem was most likely caused by the WindowsPos value.

If it happens again the two solutions are:

1) Right click on the thumbnail/title for the dev toolbar in the task bar and then select "Move" then press an arrow. Now if you move your mouse you should see the window follow your cursor around, left clicking will "detach" it from your cursor.

2) Delete the value WindowPos, don't set it to 0 as that will cause the issue to happen again, just delete the entry.

Comment: About 2), deleting just `WindowPos` doesn't make it appear. `UseDevToolsDebugger` and `Pinned` also should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above fixed my missing toolbar (on IE7 in this case), however the following did:

> Click: Tools > Internet Options > Programs > Manage add-ons > IE
>   Developer Toolbar BHO > Enable

(You can also go via Tools > Manage add-ons > Enable or Disable Add-ons.)

There may also be a 'IE Developer Toolbar' option. Enable that too.

Restart and your toolbar should reappear.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, the registry solution didn't work. Pressing f12 did nothing. What did work was going to "internet options"->advanced, and clicking "reset" on the bottom and pressing reset in the window that comes up.

Answer (score 0):

windows run command **gpedit.msc**

1. Under Local Computer policy select Administrative Templates.
2. Select windows components  ->  select Internet Explorer
3. Select Toolbars
4. Double click on the right pane Turn Off Developer tools.
5. Disable and apply the settings close IE and reopen.
6. press f12

This policy setting allows you to manage whether users have access to Developer Tools in Internet Explorer.

If you enable this policy setting, users will not have access to Developer Tools.

If you disable or do not configure this policy setting, users will have access to Developer Tools.

Make sure you have disabled the settings
because  Even Though they are saying not configured option also work .
Its not working .
So make sure you have clicked disabled.
[image]