# IE8 / IE9 developer toolbar is empty and frozen

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

Something went wrong with my IE8 developer toolbar, this is what I get when I open the toolbar:

[image: Screenshot of frozen developer toolbar in IE8]

The browser itself works fine when I disable the toolbar though.

The last time I was using the toolbar, I was debugging javascript. I don't know why it suddenly stopped working. Things I tried:

1. Restarted computer.
2. Switch to [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite), but it does not allow javascript debugging. This is a feature I       really need.
3. Installed IE9. Developer toolbar is still broken.
4. Deactivate / activate IE8. It is not easily possible to completely deinstall IE8 from Windows 7, but I did deactivate it, but to no avail.

If anybody either recognizes this problem, or knows a workaround, please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer? No pun intended.

Comment: @Flauwekeul yes, I will add that to my "Things I tried" list :)

Comment: Comments are appreciated when downvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the [IE 8 Developer Tools not working In Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234163/ie-8-developer-tools-not-working-in-windows#answer-3060498) fix, I actually got it working again. After maximizing, resizing and dragging the toolbar, at a certain point I was able to snap it back to the screen without this bug.