# Analyzing tool for React Memory Problem on Internet Explorer

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, memory, memory-leaks

I have React based application that works on Internet Explorer based browser. I cannot open developer mode of browser and  cannot inspect the browser. It just displays the application. My application has some memory problems. There is a critical leakage in the project. I wonder that is there a tool or method to find out the reason of this memory problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you set the browser so that it cannot open the dev tool correctly. Under **Tools**, is the **F12** option grayed out? Or completely missing? If this is the case, you could refer to [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/f12-does-not-open-developer-tools-nor-is-developer/023f56e4-5755-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5).

It is also possible that the dev tool has been opened, but it is minimized in the taskbar, and you cannot open it. For this case, you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234163/ie-8-developer-tools-not-working-in-windows).

If not the above, could you please provide more details about the issue？

Besides, if you need to analyze the memory usage, you could try the debugger-integrated **Memory Usage** diagnostic tool in **Visual Studio**. For more details, please refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2019).