# IE8 Developer Tools won't open

Tags: internet-explorer

Just installed IE8 on WinXP. Trying to use the Dev Tools but, clicking on the menu item or hitting F12 doesn't do anything.  I can see the option in the tools menu, just can't use it.

I've checked to make sure it wasn't opening minimized or off screen and I've checked the registry settings used to disable them.  Those registry keys don't even exists.

Suggestions?  I was going to reinstall, but, thought I'd check here first.

Comment: reinstall (15 characters filler)

Comment: reinstall (15 characters filler)

Comment: OP is asking about IE8 **Developer** Tools. How the hell is this "not programming related"? And no, it doesn't belong on SuperUser.com - it's not a trash bin for SO, we really need to stop throwing everything over there.

Comment: @ChssPly76. He's asking about getting a specific menu option to work inside of a program.  The only relation to programming is that the menu option is to show some dev tools.  Beyond that it's a problem with his computer / installation and not anywhere near the same level as "how do I use cross apply?"  He may as well have asked how to fix his print preview button.

Comment: @Chris - so you **honestly** think that this question has better chance of being answered on SuperUser.com than here? We're talking about **developer** tools. Would you migrate Eclipse / Visual Studio / what have you question to SuperUser as well just because "it's a program"?

Comment: i concur with the SO comments, this doesn't belong on SU.  send it back.

Comment: original SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633182/ie8-developer-tools-wont-open

Comment: Related: [Why isn't my IE8 Developer Tools working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960683/why-isnt-my-ie8-developer-tools-working)

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my post, those registry keys don't exist, so, nothing there to delete as mentioned in the post you linked to.

Comment: I know it's a bit late, but if you associate your accounts (from your profile page) you'll regain ownership of the question.