# Unable to see the developer tool on Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, ie-developer-tools

I am using Internet Explorer 8, by choice. I need to debug a script in it. However, no matter how many times I click the Developer Tools Icon, under Tools or when I click F12 it will not show up. Sometimes, I can see that it is minimized in the taskbar but when I actually go to click it. It will not show up...

Comment: why not debug the script in another browser? Is it your pc or a client?

Comment: The answer was here on SO. But could not find it. As far as I remember, the window is open but is hidden outside of the screen are, I think you going to have to use the keyboard short cut to move it and bring it to the viewable area.

Comment: Sometimes IE won't display the source of a page or the developer tools if the output source is malformed in some way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't my IE8 Developer Tools working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960683/why-isnt-my-ie8-developer-tools-working)

Answer (score 5):

You may do Alt+Spacebar, then hit ‘m’ and start using your arrow keys to move the window around. And also check that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960683/why-isnt-my-ie8-developer-tools-working)