# Disable auto-start of Internet Explorer 8 Developer Tools

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

Every time I start up a new instance of IE8 32bit, Developer Tools opens automatically.  How to disable that and keep F12 functional?

I have tried searching for and deleting all registry keys named IEDevTools (including under HKCU, HKLM, 64bit and 32bit registry).  I have also tried adding a DWORD named Disabled, valued 1, at the single location, under HKCU, that gets recreated by IE start-up.

None of that helped.  This is a Windows 7 64bit system that has seen multiple up- and downgrades between IE8 and IE9, and also has Chrome and Firefox.  (I have seen interaction between Chrome settings and IE settings before, but I can hardly imagine one here.)

[People who just want to put F12 to another use, which is not my case, please find your help here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944323/disable-internet-explorer-8-developer-tools)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, in my case the following procedure did the trick:

1. Pin the developer tools window by pressing the small button in the top right corner of the window.
2. Close the developer tools by clicking on the close button in the top right corner of the docked tools zone.

Now, when you open a new instance / a new tab of IE8, the tools don't come up anymore. It seems that they keep opening when you close an instance of IE8 with the tools active and unpinned (on a separate window).

Hope this works.

Comment: I have this problem on IE10. Your method doesn't work. Any good suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I did not figure out the cause, but this is how I got over this in case anyone wonders: IE8 64bit works on the same system without a problem.

(In a next step I had to move on to IE9 because IE8 64bit is not compatible with SharePoint.  Yet another step will follow after the last few IE only apps that I still need to use die out.)